# how to capture a thumbnail from a video in a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website similar to youtube, so after uploading videos (that will be in .flv format) into a folder on the project, a thumbnail has to be captured from that corresponding video.. here i am designing my page using asp.net & c#...

I have got  some code from the net, but its working only videos of size 2-3Mb....

any one can help me to work my code for large sized files..

here's my code..

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using All4DotNet;

namespace LiveStreaming
{
public class Class1
{
    public static void GrabSingle_Thumb()
    {
        //Declare object of class MediaManagerPro
        MediaManagerPro oMediaManagerPro = new MediaManagerPro();

        //Get the rooth path
        string strRootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

        //set the directory path info for ffmpeg file
        oMediaManagerPro.FFMPEG_Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe");

        //Set source file info
        oMediaManagerPro.SourceFile_Path = strRootPath + "Videos";
        oMediaManagerPro.SourceFile_Name = "HelloWorld.flv";

        //set output file info
        oMediaManagerPro.OutputFile_Path = strRootPath + "Images";

        //Single Thumb - Properties available in free version
        oMediaManagerPro.Frame_Time = "5";
        oMediaManagerPro.Image_Format = "jpg";
        oMediaManagerPro.Image_Name = "Image_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        ////Single Thumb - Properties available in full version
        //oMediaManagerPro.Width = 320;
        //oMediaManagerPro.Height = 240;

        //grab thumbnails
        MediaInfo oMediaInfo = oMediaManagerPro.Grab_Thumb();

        #region Print Output Information
        StringBuilder strOutputInfo = new StringBuilder();
        strOutputInfo.Append("Image Created = " + oMediaInfo.File_Name + "<br />");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strOutputInfo);
        #endregion
    }
  }
}
```

I got this code from http://www.helpprogrammers.com/csharpsample.aspx

Comment: Please explain what happens with larger files, do you get an exception? Do you get any kind of error message? Is your output corrupted somehow?

Comment: no code is running normally, but no thumbnail is generated for file size above 3mb..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this seems to be an option, which works all the time, FFMPEG is the solution that we can count on. You can also try the managed version of FFMPEG, that is on [codeplex](http://winffmpeg.codeplex.com/) as well, its Win-FFMPEG. That might help.